# My if statement won't respond to string inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't get this to respond to the input. It prints 'You typed that like you had a choice!' no matter what I type

```
    redy = raw_input('Are you ready for this amazingness?')

        if redy == 'yes' or 'Yes' or 'Yup' or 'yup' or 'ya' or 'Ya':

            print'You typed that like you had a choice!'
```

Comment: Tip: Use `redy.lower()`

Comment: `if any(keyword == redy.lower() for keyword in ["yes", "ya", "yup"]):`

Comment: `redy == 'yes' or redy == 'Yes'` <- you forgot the `redy ==` part after every `or`

Comment: Thanks for the help.